# Use z3Py to prove the equivalence/difference of ranges of two expressions

Tags: python, z3

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

a, b = Ints("a b")
s.add(a > 2)
s.add(b > 0)
s.add(Or(Exists(a, ForAll(b, a != b)), Exists(b, ForAll(a, a != b))))

s.check() # print "unsat"
```

I am trying to prove the difference of ranges of `a` and `b`. This can be done by locating an assignment to `b` of value `1` which is beyond the range of `a`.

However, the program above gives unexpected `unsat`. I wonder why and whether there is more efficient way to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0):

`ForAll` means exactly that: *all* numbers, i.e. `Exists(a, ForAll(b, a != b))` is always false because there is no `Int` that's different from all `Int`s and thus the third assertion is unsatisfiable all by itself. You want something like `s.add(Exists(a, (Exists (b, And(Not(a > 2),  b > 0)))))`.

Also, note that you use two different `a` and `b`. `Exists(a, ...)` does not quantify over an existing variable, but introduces a new variable that's accidentally called by the same name as your global (existential) `a`, `b`.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification of `ForAll` and `Exists`! While I think the proposition you give can not prove their difference, maybe something like `Exists(tmp, And(Not(tmp > 2), tmp > 0))`.